# DataGridView Virtual mode auto size row on scrolling

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to use the virtual mode of a DataGridView since I have more than 150k rows (always 2 columns). The data in the DataGridView is extracted from a file and is read-only(users can't add or remove rows). However, some of my rows needs to have a greater height than the others since the data displayed in it is on multiple lines.

I am currently filling my DataGridView like this:

```
private struct ContactEntry
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Addr { get; set; }
};

private void UpdateDataGridView(List<Contact> listContact)
{    
    List<ContactEntry> newList = new List<ContactEntry>();
    for (int index = 0; index < listContact.Count; index++)
    {
        Contact ct = listContact[index];
        string addresses = string.Empty;

        if (Contact.Addrs != null)
        {
            // Construct list of addresses
            foreach (string addr in Contact.Addrs)
            {
                addresses = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", addresses, Environment.NewLine, addr);
            }
            // Removes first environment new line
            addresses = addresses.Remove(0, 2);

            var entry = new ContactEntry();
            entry.Name = Contact.Name;
            entry.Addr = addresses;
            newList.Add(entry);
        }
    }
    _dgvContacts = newList;
    _dgvContacts.CellValueNeeded += _dgvContacts_CellValueNeeded;
    // Set the row count
    _dgvContacts.RowCount = newList.Count;
    _dgvContacts.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
    _dgvContacts.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells;
    if (_dgvContacts.CurrentCell != null)
    {
        _dgvContacts.CurrentCell.Selected = false;
    }
}

private void _dgvContacts_CellValueNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
{
    switch (_dgvContacts.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name)
    {
        case "Name":
        e.Value = _dgvContacts[e.RowIndex].Name;
        break;

        case "Addresses":
        e.Value = _dgvContacts[e.RowIndex].Addr;
        break;
    }
}
```

With this, the UI loads quickly because of the virtual mode, but when the form loads, only the height of the first visible rows are adjusted. When I scroll down, the data in the rows are changed for new values from the list, but the height are not changing. However, when I resize the form, the rows height are updated like it should.

Comment: Try: "_dgvContacts.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;".

Comment: @Graffito Do I have to use set this property somewhere specific? Because I tried your suggestion and it does not work.

Comment: Be careful when using AllCells mode when the grid is in VirtualMode. This will call the CellValueNeeded event for every cell to determine the sizes to set thus negating the purpose of the Virtual mode. I had this very issue with a million row dataset and it locked up my system for minutes.